# Java Overriding function that one of the parameters are constant in the child class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have a service that read and write data based on a key-value pairs. The service is generic.

I want to implement a similar class, that extends the class I described, **but in the base class the key is constant**.

The problem is, that If I try to override the read and write functions, they both will have the key parameter in them, although it is const.

How can I implement and override in this case? Is it possible or only without the inheritence?

**My `BaseService.java`**

```
class BaseService {
    private HashMap<String, String> storage = new HashMap<String, String>();

    void write(String key, String value) {
        storage.put(key, value);
    }

    String read(String key) {
        return storage.get(key);
    }
}
```

**and `ChildService.java`**

```
class ChildService extends BaseService {
    static final String KEY = 'const-key';
    @override
    void write(String value) {
        storage.put(KEY, value);
    }

    @override
    String read() {
        return storage.get(KEY);
    }
}
```

It isn't possible to override this way since the signature is now different.

Comment: You can override `read()` and ignore passed parameter. Is it OK for you? If yes I will prepare full answer.

Comment: You're correct - there isn't a direct override ability.  Normally in this case the base class methods would be protected and only the derived classes methods would be public.  That way no one can call it with an invalid key.

Comment: @Boken isn't it weird to have parameters in the function's signature, but then it won't use them. I thought about it but told myself this is weird

Comment: Yes, it's weird. There is no good solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseService {
    HashMap<String, String> storage = new HashMap<String, String>();

    abstract String getKey();

    void write(String key, String value) {
        storage.put(key, value);
    }

    String read(String key) {
        return storage.get(key);
    }

    String read() {
        return storage.get(getKey());
    }

    void write(String value) {
        storage.put(getKey(), value);
    }

}

public class ChildService extends BaseService {

    static final String KEY = "const-key";

    @Override
    String getKey() {
        return KEY;
    }
}
```

Comment: But then what happens to use of ChildService, someone else won't know if it needs to use read/write with key or without, and if putting proected it then kind of missing the point of creating two different methods.